# Google Oauth2 api - Omniauth Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, oauth-2.0, omniauth

Currently I'm recovering the omniauth information perfectly fine using the typical setup for omniauth gems.

I'm retrieving the access_token as a string and storing it into an Authorization model that is associated to a main Users model.

So, getting to my problem.

I need to access the calenders api and in the docs I see many references like this...

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3//users/me/calendarList/calendarId
```

This seems fairly intuitive.  I want to access this in conjunction with the access token that I have retrieved.  Something along the lines of this...

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3//users/me/calendarList/calendarId?access_token=blah
```

so that I can load it directly and more streamlined into Backbone models.  However, I don't see anything in the docs and when I try the implementation, it consistently throws me 404s of "Not found" (which is rather annoying and undescriptive.  I'd prefer if it threw 422s but I suppose that's a discussion for somewhere else.)

Is there anything in the docs that provide an example implementation of how to access the info with a token?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit more research and found out about the google ruby client gem that was released.  Basically,  we have to feed the token into the Google::Client instance and pump out an object that has a defined set of methods that can be used on it.

I created a special case controller to handle this logic to render out a suitable api.

TO-DO: Will get into specifics in a bit.  Currently I'm very tired.